# What objects other than Button can take rules for their Appearance options?

Tags: front-end, options, undocumented

So I was messing with the `ServiceConnect` dialog and I stumbled upon this hidden in a `ButtonBox` in its code:

```
Appearance -> { 
  "Default" -> <red_rounded_image> 
    (*use ServiceConnect@"ChemSpider" to see what I mean*), 
  "Hover" -> <red_raised_image>,
  "Pressed" -> <red_depressed_image>
  }
```

and I confirmed that this also works for `Button`. I had no idea `Appearance` could even be rules (although Kuba points out this is briefly mentioned in the `Appearance` docs), but looking at it, I'm wondering, are there other objects that do this? Moreover, are there other rules I can use for `Button`?

This is huge for me as this way I won't have to write potentially buggy `Dynamic` code to change the appearance of my objects.

#### Edit

Can confirm `"Disabled"` is another option for `Button`.

#### Edit 2:

These also work with [`Panel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Panel.html) see also [`"ButtonType"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153096/38205)

Comment: Buggy Dynamic is at least something you can complain on to WRI Support, in contrary to undocumented syntax :)

Comment: True, but I'm afraid the `Dynamic` bugginess is more likely to be my doing than theirs.

Comment: Hmm, it seems it is even documented. In Appearance/Details but without any info about states names.

Comment: Right you are. I guess I must have always ignored that bit, given that `When an object can be in several different states, the setting for Appearance can be given in the form {"cond1"->app1,"cond2"->app2,...}` doesn't give us any info on when this syntax applies.