# How can I make a button that imitates DefaultButton and CancelButton?

Tags: front-end

Both [`DefaultButton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefaultButton.html) and [`CancelButton`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CancelButton.html) are very convenient, in that they allow one to use `` FEPrivate`FindAndClickDefaultButton `` and `` FEPrivate`FindAndClickCancelButton ``. Unfortunately `DefaultButton` doesn't allow me to use custom appearances. How can I get that behavior?

Comment: According to the documentation, `DefaultButton` should have the same options as `Button`. It seems that the `Appearance` option should work.  You should report to WRI to see if it is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is in the `Appearance` list. I found this here:

```
FileNameJoin@{
  PacletFind["CloudObject"][[1]]["Location"],
  "Kernel",
  "Dialogs.m"
  }
```

The appearances use listed default / hover / pressed / disabled appearances a la [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134779/38205) question. There's another appearance option called `"ButtonType"` which can be set to `"Cancel"` or `"Default"` to get the desired behavior. e.g.:

```
Append[
 FrontEndResource["NotebookTemplatingExpressions", 
  "ButtonDefaultAppearance"],
 "ButtonType" -> "Default"
 ]
```

I use this, for example, [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/AuthDialogs.m)

This works, of course, because `CreateDialog` sticks this into a dialog by default:

```
NotebookEventActions -> {"ReturnKeyDown" :> 
   FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`FindAndClickDefaultButton[]], {"MenuCommand",
     "EvaluateCells"} :> 
   FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`FindAndClickDefaultButton[]], {"MenuCommand",
     "HandleShiftReturn"} :> 
   FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`FindAndClickDefaultButton[]], {"MenuCommand",
     "EvaluateNextCell"} :> 
   FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`FindAndClickDefaultButton[]], 
  "EscapeKeyDown" :> (FE`Evaluate[
     FEPrivate`FindAndClickCancelButton[]]; DialogReturn[$Failed]), 
  "WindowClose" :> (FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`FindAndClickCancelButton[]];
     DialogReturn[$Failed])}
```

And then we can imitate that like so:

```
CreateDocument[
 {
  Hyperlink["Home Page", 
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/main.html",
   Appearance ->
    {
     "Default" -> None,
     "ButtonType" -> "Default"
     }
   ],
  Hyperlink["Cancel Page", "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com",
   Appearance ->
    {
     "Default" -> None,
     "ButtonType" -> "Cancel"
     }
   ]
  },
 NotebookEventActions -> {"ReturnKeyDown" :> 
    FE`Evaluate[
     FEPrivate`FindAndClickDefaultButton[]], {"MenuCommand", 
     "EvaluateCells"} :> 
    FE`Evaluate[
     FEPrivate`FindAndClickDefaultButton[]], {"MenuCommand", 
     "HandleShiftReturn"} :> 
    FE`Evaluate[
     FEPrivate`FindAndClickDefaultButton[]], {"MenuCommand", 
     "EvaluateNextCell"} :> 
    FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`FindAndClickDefaultButton[]], 
   "EscapeKeyDown" :> (FE`Evaluate[
      FEPrivate`FindAndClickCancelButton[]]; DialogReturn[$Failed]), 
   "WindowClose" :> (FE`Evaluate[
      FEPrivate`FindAndClickCancelButton[]]; DialogReturn[$Failed])}
 ]
```

Where just pressing `Enter` or `Cancel` presses those [`Hyperlinks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hyperlink.html).