# Making a header-body-footer interface without Grid and Column

Tags: front-end, customization, undocumented

I want to make a nice little interface with a header-bar, a main-body, and a footer.

[`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) and [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html) based constructs can get messy quickly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

So I did this in emulation of the training dialog in the new machine learning stuff:

[image: td]

I looked at that and decided to [apply nine-patch images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161692/38205) to the task

In my collection of formatting tools I defined a [`NinePatchNameTag` function](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/45736b3cab82aa692964b24a00268c88301c5d60/Packages/FormattingTools.m#L365) that defines this type of appearance in a nine-patch image:

```
nt =
 NinePatchNameTag[
  {RoundingRadius -> {15, 1}, ImageSize -> 50},
  {ImageSize -> 5},
  {ImageSize -> 30}
  ]
```

[image: nine-patch]

Then I made some nine-patch button appearances:

```
ba =
 Map[
  #[[1]] ->
    NinePatchCreate[
     PillGradientImage[#[[2]], ImageSize -> {10, 25}, 
      RoundingRadius -> 2],
     {1, 1},
     {1, 15}
     ] &,
  {
   "Default" ->
    {GrayLevel[.9], GrayLevel[.6]},
   "Hover" ->
    {GrayLevel[.9], GrayLevel[.7]},
   "Pressed" ->
    {GrayLevel[.7], GrayLevel[.8]}
   }
  ]
```

[image: buttons]

And finally I wrapped this all together by using `AttachCell` to make floating header and footer cells that will overlay on this base nine-patch appearance:

```
DynamicModule[
 {panelBox,
  buttonCell,
  headerCell,
  myText, nt = nt, ba = ba},
 Panel[
  Pane[
   ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}],
   ImageSize -> {500, 300}, 
   Scrollbars -> Automatic
   ],
  Appearance -> nt
  ],
 Initialization :>
  {
   panelBox =
    First@FrontEndExecute@
      FrontEnd`ObjectChildren[EvaluationBox[]],
   buttonCell =
    FrontEndExecute@
     FrontEnd`AttachCell[
      panelBox,
      Cell[
       BoxData@ToBoxes@
         Button[
          Style["Open Text", GrayLevel[.3]],
          openText[],
          Appearance -> ba
          ]
       ],
      {Offset[{-2, -1}, -2], {Right, Bottom}},
      {Right, Bottom},
      "ClosingActions" -> {"EvaluatorQuit"}
      ],
   headerCell =
    FrontEndExecute@
     FrontEnd`AttachCell[
      panelBox,
      Cell["Text Viewer", "Chapter"],
      {Offset[{0, 0}, -3], {Center, Top}},
      {Center, Top},
      "ClosingActions" -> {"EvaluatorQuit"}
      ]
   },
 Deinitialization :>
  {NotebookDelete /@ {headerCell, buttonCell}}
 ]
```

[image: asdasdasd]

This gives good response time, restricts the content *only* to that center area, and provides a generally attractive interface. Obviously it could be tweaked further by providing different name-tag colors or using a gradient image in the nine-patch headers and footers.

The main issue with this is those `AttachedCell`s. These can sometimes cause slight glitches in the FE, like when editing a cell via the `RawData` wrapper.
 (they disappear I haven't configured the `DynamicModule` to resurrect them).

This could serve as a decent template for making more interesting interfaces, though.