# Get all built-in image files for styling buttons and panels

Tags: front-end, undocumented

Mathematica [makes use of nine-patch images](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161692/38205) in styling its resizable interfaces like `Panel` and `Button`. Nicer than remaking new ones for our own work, though, would be to repurpose the internal ones.

The general way this works is via something like:

```
Button[
 Style["Blah", Hue[0, .1, .9], Bold],
 Null,
 FrameMargins -> {{10, 10}, {0, 0}},
 Appearance ->
  {
   "Default" -> 
    FrontEnd`FileName[{"Dialogs", "Activation"}, 
     "RedButton-Default.9.png"],
   "Hover" -> 
    FrontEnd`FileName[{"Dialogs", "Activation"}, 
     "RedButton-Hover.9.png"],
   "Pressed" ->
    FrontEnd`FileName[{"Dialogs", "Activation"}, 
     "RedButton-Pressed.9.png"]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

The question, then is how do we find all possible options for this `` FrontEnd`FileName ``.

I'm gonna leave this question open in case someone has a really smooth answer, but I thought I'd lay it out there that the complete search path for these looks like:

```
ToFileName /@ 
 AbsoluteCurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {PrivatePaths, "Bitmaps"}]
```

So at a minimum we can use:

```
fefnames =
  With[{fp = FileNameSplit[#[[2]]]},
     FrontEnd`FileName[Evaluate@Most[fp], Evaluate[Last[fp]]]
     ] & /@
   StringSplit[
    FileNames[
     "*.9.png",
     ToFileName /@ 
      AbsoluteCurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {PrivatePaths, 
        "Bitmaps"}],
     3
     ],
    FileNameJoin@{"SystemResources", "Bitmaps"}
    ];
```

And we can visualize these like:

```
Dataset[AssociationMap[
  RawBoxes@DynamicBox@FEPrivate`ImportImage[#] &, fefnames]]
```

[image]

I'm down for anything cleaner or more complete, though (or if someone wants to repurpose that into their own answer I'll delete this)