# Margin-colored text in box in Graphics

Tags: graphics, style

I am looking to put quite a bit of text in a graphic. I want the text to be in a box with rounded corners and the box to drop a shadow. I want each paragraph to have a small hanging indent (`LineIndent -> 1`). I also want each paragraph in the box to have a different margin color that would flag the different types of paragraphs to the reader. Ideally, I would like that color to be a rectangle that is intense at the top and bottom and fades or gradients out in the middle. Perhaps a different way to say this is that, instead of a background color, I want the text to get only the left side of a box around it, that to be thick, colored and to fade out and back in.

This is a sketch of the direction I am going:

[image]

Here is a sample of code that does not work:

```
Graphics[{Circle[], 
  Text[Boxed@
    Style["The lazy fox jumped over the quick dog. The lazy fox \
jumped over the quick dog. The lazy fox jumped over the quick dog. \
The lazy fox jumped over the quick dog. The lazy fox jumped over the \
quick dog.", Background -> LightRed, FontFamily -> "Georgia"]
   , {1, 1}]
  }]
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something to get you started:

```
frame[col_] := ImageResize[Image[Rasterize[
     Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@Graphics[{
          {LinearGradientFilling[{0, 0.45, 0.55, 1} -> {col, 
              Lighter[col, 0.9], Lighter[col, 0.9], col}, Bottom],
           Rectangle[{0, 0}, {3, 20}]},
          AbsoluteThickness@1,
          Black,
          Rectangle[{-1, 10}, {0, 11}],
          Rectangle[{3, 20}, {4, 21}],
          Rectangle[{4, -1}, {5, 0}],
          Rectangle[{6, 0}, {7, 20}]
          },
         PlotRangePadding -> None,
         ImageSize -> {8, 22}
         ],
      CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
      CellFrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
      ],
     RasterSize -> 2 {8, 22},
     ImageSize -> 2 {8, 22}
     ], ImageResolution -> Automatic], 8, Resampling -> "Nearest"];
Image[ImageResize[frame[Red], 120, Resampling -> "Nearest"], 
 ImageSize -> 50]
```

This produces an image that can be used as a [9-patch appearance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161692/36508):

[image]

We can now use this appearance for the panels for the individual paragraphs, and apply the remaining styling:

```
Graphics[
 {DropShadowing[],
  Text@Style[Framed[
     Pane[
      Column[
       {
        Panel[
         "The lazy fox jumped over the quick dog.The lazy fox jumped \
over the quick dog.The lazy fox jumped over the quick dog.", 
         Appearance -> {"Default" -> frame[Red]}],
        Panel[
         "The lazy fox jumped over the quick dog.The lazy fox jumped \
over the quick dog.The lazy fox jumped over the quick dog.", 
         Appearance -> {"Default" -> frame[Blue]}]
        },
       Left
       ],
      UpTo@150
      ],
     RoundingRadius -> 5,
     Background -> White
     ],
    PanelBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Georgia", 
        LineIndent -> 1, TextAlignment -> Left}}
    ]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing your results in my 13.1 version. My text gets covered with all the columns of your first graph and they do not start to the left of the text; they function as its background. Could you please explain your code more? Also, your text is centered; I cannot figure out where would an `Alignment->Left` option belongs.

Comment: @NicholasG Sorry, completely forgot about the `TextAlignment` option, I added it now. As for the other issue: It seems version 13.1 has some "interesting" behavior for `Rasterize`, should be fixed now

Comment: I am stumped at italicizing or making bold some words in the text. If I use `Row@{Style[...],Style[...],...}` the text gets messed up with extra line breaks and different widths. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `"normal text " <> ToString[Style["styled text ", Italic], StandardForm] <> "more normal text"`, or equivalently, use the Format menu to style the string as you want

Comment: It Does not work: `Panel[ToString[Style["The lazy fox ", Italic]<>"jumped over ... dog.", Appearance -> {"Default" -> frame[Red]}]` produces normal text, no italic.

Comment: That's because you forgot the second argument (`StandardForm`) of `ToString` - at least for me, your example works as expected if I add that